# Show all whitespace errors using Airline

Tags: vim, whitespace, syntastic, vim-airline

I'm using *Vim* with *Airline* plugin and whitespace extension and it shows me `mixed-indent` or `trailing-whitespace` errors in the bottom right corner. 
[image]
But there's only one (first) error with the line number there. I'd like to check all line numbers with errors like it is possible to check *Syntastic* errors using `:Errors` command. 
[image]
Is there any way to do it ? Or the only solution is to correct the error and than go to the next one when *Airline* updates its status ?

Comment: `Syntastic` plugin keeps a list with location of every error, whereas `airline`'s extension indicating whitespace errors performs multiple top-down checks looking for first occurrence and doesn't store location of the next one. So I think it's not possible without rewriting `whitespace` extension.